# Rails API 5.1.4 Active Storage - Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, rails-activestorage

I'm having trouble setting up local Active Record Storage with my Rails 5 API. `gem 'activestorage'` and `rake active_storage:install` work fine as they're generating the migration file and *config/storage_services.yml* (which confused me as it's normally just *config/storage.yml*)

I followed the documentation and put `require "active_storage"` in my *config/application.rb* (I tried doing `require "active_storage/engine"` too but it didn't work). It seems to be breaking in *config/environments/development.rb* at the line `config.active_storage.service = :local` as it throws this error:

```
NoMethodError: Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Google is not being particularly helpful, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does renaming ```config/storage_services.yml``` to ```config/storage.yml``` fix the problem? Because error message looks like Rails cannot find config file.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Does the solution at https://github.com/rails/activestorage/issues/33 not work? It's the exact same error message. Essentially, "Make a copy of your `config/storage_services.yml` file to `config/storage_services_backup.yml`. Then delete the amazon, google, and mirror sections from the original file. Otherwise, your server won't start, because it will be looking for keys and files that don't exist."

Answer (score 0):

You can check if active_storage is installed by `bundle show activestorage` I believe it is not because active_storage only pre-installed after 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this came really late, I had the same issue trying to add the gem into my Rails 5.1 app.

After some debugging, I figured that the problem is in the `config/storage_services.yml`, specifically the following `amazon` part:

```
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.secrets.aws[:access_key_id] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.secrets.aws[:secret_access_key] %>
```

Even if you comment these lines out, the `ERB` will still try to evaluate the code, and if you don't set the `aws` secrets beforehand, the error will occur.

So, just remove the whole `amazon` section if you're not going to use it. Or set the secret correctly if you do.